# Error retrieving parent for element, with parent being Widget.AppCompat.*

Tags: android, xml, android-appcompat

I am trying to change the default color (white) of the text in overflow space of the action bar (I am following the tutorials at android developers site, and I am trying to experiment with the one with the action bar).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
          parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTheme.MyActionBar</item>


        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTheme.MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme.MyActionBar"
          parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@color/bright_green</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTheme.MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTheme.MyActionBar.actionOverflowButtonStyle</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
    </style>


    <!-- ActionBar Text Styles -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme.MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle"
           parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title" >

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_green</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme.MyActionBar.actionOverflowButtonStyle"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_green</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

At the style `CustomActionBarTheme.MyActionBar.actionOverflowButtonStyle` I cannot set the parent as `Widget.AppCompat.*`, due to AppCompat not being available as an option.
I am getting this:
`Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow'.`

Also, I think I should change the parent of `CustomActionBarTheme.MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle` as well to be a style from AppCompat library?

Comment: Are you targeting api level 18?

Comment: @hichris123: Yes, target api leve 18, minimum level api 7.